# Mocking Web Services for client layer unit testing

Tags: web-services, unit-testing

I have a business rule visual studio class library (.NET 2.0) project that takes a dependency on Dynamics Crm Web Services - a classic SOAP web reference as opposed to a WCF endpoint. I want to unit test those business rules without having a real crm instance behind it. Adding a web reference doesn't produce an interface that I can fake. It does generate c# in my project that I think I can fake if I can create the interface. I don't think I need to actually navigate HTTP and get into all of the protocol stuff.

I saw Joh Skeet's [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/09/08/how-does-everyone-else-mock-web-services.aspx). Alas I didn't want to write any code and I'm hoping a tool has been written since then that might help. I tried some of his steps but concluded that he is smarter than me and I couldn't make that work.

I am aware of SoapUI, however, I was hoping for pure unit tests that would work in a CI build environment.

Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to mock something which doesn't come with an interface, is to build your own wrapper around it.

the code you want to mock, say the webservice stuff:

```
class AutoGeneratedStuff
{
    public string GeneratedMethodYouUse()
    {...}
    public string GeneratedMethodYouDontNeed()
    {...}
}
```

you then make an interface which covers only the bits of the code you need:

```
public interface IWebServiceClient
{
    string MethodYouUse();
}
```

and a concrete wrapper class which implements it, which has a dependency to the generated stuff

```
class WebServiceClient : IWebServiceClient
{
    private AutoGeneratedStuff _stuff;

    public WebService(AutogeneratedStuff stuff)
    {
         _stuff = stuff;
    }

    public string MethodYouUse()
    {
        return _stuff.MethodYouUse();
    }
}
```

then, in your code when you would have called the generated class, call your interface instead. In your unit tests, you can mock the interface, either using a mocking framework, or by implementing the interface with another concrete class that has no dependencies to the generated stuff

Comment: nice explanation, I don't see why it hasn't been voted up before.