# Mocking an asynchronous web service in Angular unit tests

Tags: angularjs, web-services, unit-testing, firebase, filepicker.io

I'm building an Angular app, and I'm writing unit tests for it. Yay unit tests. I want to mock a particular web service that I'm using (Filepicker.io), which has both a REST API as well as a Javascript API. In my code I use the Javascript API in calls like

```
filepicker.store(file,
        {    
            options: 'go',
            right: 'here'
        },   
        // filepicker's success callback
        function(resultObject){ 
            // do stuff with the returned object
        }
```

I know that I could use the $httpBackend provider if I were interacting with Filepicker's REST API, but since my application's code isn't doing that, I'm wondering if/how I could mock an asynchronous API call like this in an Angular unit test.

Do I just override the store method (or the whole filepicker object) in context of my test suite and make it return dummy data of my choosing? That's what they're doing with [AngularFire development](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/tests/mocks/mocks.firebase.js), with a library that overrides the 'real' Firebase backend service.

Alternately, could I wrap the method in something that uses $httpBackend, so I can use all those handy $httpBackend methods like respond? What's the right strategy here? The first one seems like a simpler and cleaner idea.

Here are some other questions that were similar but ultimately not clear enough for me to fully understand.

[AngularJS: unit testing application based on Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657965/angularjs-unit-testing-application-based-on-google-maps-api/13685197#13685197)

[Unit testing Web Service responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768196/unit-testing-web-service-responses)

[Mocking Web Services for client layer unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030597/mocking-web-services-for-client-layer-unit-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first set your SDK as an injectable Service so it can be used more easily by your angular app

```
myApp.factory('FilePicker',function(){
   //likely coming from global namespace 
   return filepicker;
})
.controller('ctrl',['FilePicker',function(FilePicker){
    //use File picker
}];
```

Now you should be able to inject a mock instead of the real implementation for your tests.
An example with a our controller

```
describe('ctrl test', function(){
    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
        var mockService={} // here set up a mock

        ctrl=$controller('ctrl',{FilePicker:mockService});
    }));
});
```

Comment: It would behoove you to use $window.filepicker, which allows the filepicker service to easily be mocked even if it's directly included somewhere instead of via a service, and also prevents jshint from complaining about global variables.